# Limiting/controlling the users ability to print in Java

Tags: java, printing

I am looking to right an application that limits the number of times a user can print something, its there anything in Java that will allow me to control the printing dialogue to this aim?

Im going to look into these:
http://www.wildcrest.com/Software/J2PrinterWorks/documentation/J2Printer14.html

http://www.softframeworks.com/products/products.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with [J2Printer](http://www.wildcrest.com/Software/J2PrinterWorks/documentation/J2Printer.html). I allows the suppression of the print dialogue.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably something you'll need to implement yourself as it is **too-specific** a requirement to have been included in the JDK's API.

Assuming you've developed a standalone Swing application you could consider using the [**Preferences**](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) class to store the number of times a user has printed a document for a given date.  On Windows this translates to **storing information in the registry** and is therefore "hidden" from the user to a certain extent, but would allow you to reset the value in an emergency using regedit.

The advantage of this approach is that the user cannot circumvent the print-threshold by simply restarting the application.